# How can I use data from v-for list in inline css with v-bind:style?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

This probably has a simple solution it's just been a while since I've used vue:

I'm trying to pass data that's pulled from a list of colors into inline css to change the background color of each item, here's an example:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="color in colors">{{ color.value }}</li>
</ul>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
        colors: [
            { value: '#00205b'},
            { value: '#0033a0'},
            { value: '#0084d4'}
        ],
    }
  })
</script>
```

I'd like to use the data pulled from `color.value` and place it into something like `v-bind:style="background-color: { color.value }"` but I can't figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: check this: [vue binding](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this: (See [style binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax-1))

```
<li v-for="color in colors" v-bind:style="{backgroundColor: color.value}">
{{ color.value }}
</li>
```

Or,

```
:style="{'background-color': color.value}"
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. I had the wrong syntax when using 
`v-bind:style="{backgroundColor: color.value}"`.

Comment: Just to clarify my mind a bit, this would technically work as well right? `v-bind:style="'background-color': color.value"`. I'm trying to understand if backgroundColor is the same as above.

Comment: @Craig First, correct your typo, the apostrophe is used outside left curly brace.

Comment: @Craig You need to use object syntax or array syntax... but plain string won't as you're trying to.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a computed property and extend each `color` object in the `colors` array with a style property. This style property will contain the styling for each element.

Finally, use the computed property in the `v-for` directive instead of the original array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#list',

  data() {
    return {
      colors: [{
          value: '#00205b'
        },
        {
          value: '#0033a0'
        },
        {
          value: '#0084d4'
        }
      ],
    };
  },

  computed: {
    extendedColors() {
      return this.colors.map(color => ({ ...color,
        style: {
          backgroundColor: color.value
        }
      }));
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<ul id="list">
  <li v-for="color in extendedColors" :style="color.style">
    {{ color.value }}
  </li>
</ul>
```